# The sort direction is reset when the data drawn by react-window is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-window

##### Achievement goal

- Draw a large amount of data on the table
- Sticky header (scroll only the body)
- Sortable by clicking the cell in the header
- The data in that row can be updated by pressing the button

##### Example code (Minimal Reproducible)

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-mclaren-b1vnhm

##### Using plugin

react-window : FixedSizeList
react-table : useSortBy

##### Question

Each one has been realized, but there is a bug.

Steps to reproduce

1. Sort (some header)
2. Press the button

Why reset the sort direction, when update data?

Comment: Please update your question here to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the relevant code you've an issue working with.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated. Please see item 'Example code (Minimal Reproducible)'.

Answer (score 0):

following, the answer.(react-table doc)

[how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes).